# onChange() doesn't fire

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I'm trying to make cascading selects in a form, but I'm having trouble getting it to work. It seems that the onChange() in my select element won't fire.

the php

```
$flight_sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_flr_flights";
$flight_result = mysql_query($flight_sql);
echo '<select name="location" id="select-location onChange="changeSecond(this.value)">';
echo '<option value="">Select</option>';
while ($flt_loc_rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($flight_result)) {
    $loc_id = $flt_loc_rows["location_id"];
    $loc_name = $flt_loc_rows["location_name"];
    echo '<option value="'.$loc_id.'">'.$loc_name.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

the javascript

```
    function changeSecond(first){
alert('dasda');
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        var res=xmlhttp.responseText;
        document.getElementById("second").innerHTML=res;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","reservations-plane.php?first="+first,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

reservations-plane.php

```
    global $wpdb, $page_url;
    $location=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["first"]);
    echo $userid.'ddd';
    $flight_sql = "SELECT ".$location." FROM wp_flr_flights GROUP BY ".$location;
    $flight_result = mysql_query($flight_sql);
    echo '<select name="plane_type_choose">';
    while ($flt_plane_rows = mysql_fetch_row($flight_result)) {
        $plain_id = $flt_plane_rows["plane_id"];
        $plane_type = $flt_plane_rows["plane_type"];
        echo '<option value="'.$flt_plane_rows[0].'">'.$flt_plane_rows[0].'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Is `$function changeSecond(first){` just a copy/paste typo?  Because it should be `function changeSecond(...`.

Comment: It looks you miss the ending quoutes after your id attribute (before the onchange trigger)

Comment: When asking a Javascript question, it isn't important to show the `php` or `mysql` code.  The only thing we need to to see is the rendered `HTML` and the `Javascript`.  That said, looks like the other comments address your problem.

Comment: You should really refactor your code. Consider adding some air in there, a new-line won't kill anyone. Mix that up with some comments and it will look great.

Answer (score 4):

You have a misspelling in your code:

`$function` ... should be `function`

```
function changeSecond(first){
   ...
}
```

Note: Check your error codes

Also there is an error in your html produced.

```
echo '<select name="location" id="select-location onChange=....>';
```

the ending double quote is missing for the id attribute.

Comment: Yes the $ was just a typo. good catch on the id that was what was causing the onChange to not work. But the cascading selects still don't work. I don't understand why this is so hard.

Comment: @gilgimech then the missing double quote must be the problem